# How to check ajax return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call and it retunrs some value. Now i need to check the value in javascript. How  can i do it

```
$('#cm').blur(function () {
     var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;
     $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: "/validatecm/" + cmnumber,
         cache: false,
         asyn: false,
         data: cmnumber,
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data)

         },
         error: function (data) {
             alert(data)

         }
     })

 });
```

Now i need to access the "data" in my javascript submitformfunction. Any help wil be appreciated

Comment: Just need to check: Before the edit there was a script tag but no document.ready around the jQuery. Is your document ready before this is being executed (script is at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: It's `async`, not `asyn`, and you should'nt turn it off.

Comment: Just assign the data to some global variable and use it anywhere!

Comment: *related* [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Comment: Please don't assign the data to some global variable. Using globals frivolously like that makes code harder to maintain. If that value is only to be passed to that function, that's the only place it should exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
 success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
     useInAnotherFunction(data);

 }

 function useInAnotherFunction(data)
 {
  ...use here
 }
```

If you use  console.log(data); you can view clearly data what you have

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution  with this answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You are already accessing the data here

```
alert(data)
```

If you still want to access it outside your success callback then make it like this

```
success: function(data) {
         YourFunctionCall(data)

    }
```